# Bash - multiline Whiptail backtitle

Tags: linux, bash, whiptail

I'm trying to add multiple lines to Whiptail dialogs backtitles.

I tried:

```sh
whiptail --clear --backtitle "asdf \n asdf \n asdf" \
         --title test --yesno test \
         0 0 "test" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

```sh
whiptail --clear --backtitle "asdf
asdf
asdf" \
         --title test --yesno test \
         0 0 "test" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

```sh
whiptail --clear --backtitle "$(printf '%s\n' asdf asdf asdf)" \
         --title test --yesno test \
         0 0 "test" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

Is there a way to have a multi line backtitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Looking at the source that is hosted [here](https://pagure.io/newt) you can see that the [backtitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUBtq.png) text is always drawn in the first column and first row.

But any position can be put there. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uotJF.png) is the source of that function.
I cloned the repo and verified that putting something other than position (0,0) where the backtitle option is parsed will have the text start wherever you want.